# PHP script restarting from top

Tags: php, apache, shell-exec

I have a long-running php script that does some ffmpeg stuff. It works perfectly fine on my dev box (amazon ec2). But on production, (clone of the dev box), the php script resets from the top after 60 seconds.

```
<?php
function convert() {
    error_log('Executing ffmpeg');
    shell_exec(ffmpeg.....);
}
?>
```

so calling this service while looking at the error log and top. i get

```
20:32:04 Executing ffmpeg
20:33:04 Executing ffmpeg
20:34:04 Executing ffmpeg
```

and in top i get 3 ffmpeg

Any idea what in php would cause it to reset from the top?

Comment: Is it possible that your script is getting executed 3 times? I know of no mechanism in PHP to 'reset' it back to the first line outside of a loop and goto.

Comment: Looks like a daemon is calling the script

Comment: Is this running from a cronjob?  If so, what is in the minute column of the line setting it up?